# SelectInput: selected value is not saved on a multi steps form

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using a multi steps form when I click on previous to go to the previous step the selected value is not there and the selectinput is blank.

This is the code I am using:

```html
<SelectInput value={this.state.value}
    onChange={this.handleDropDownChange}
    errorText={err.State}
    maxHeight={200}
    name="State"
    floatingLabelText={messages.STATE[lang]}
    floatingLabelFixed={true}
>
    {
        this.props.ci.StatesOfUS.map((element) => {
            return <MenuItem value={element.Value} primaryText={element.Value} />
        })                     
    }           
</SelectInput>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because your component is unmounted when you go to a previous step and all the state is lost. In such a case you could pull up the state to a parent component. See https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html.